# Использование javascript массива в foreach

Tags: c#

Получаю из браузера вот такой javascript массив:

```
["StarSeries EU Group Stage D2", "LIVE: Empire 1-1 Alternate (bo3), StarSeries 13: E", "Буст 3168 - 4500  (7-0) + Розыгрыш Арканы http://v", "WIN WIN WIN WIN WIN", "BACK FROM IEM! - Overwatch in queue", "Rekkles", "UberDanger - Drunk stream to end all drunk streams", "CounterForces w/ @summit1g.", "FALLOUT Z IZAKIEM!", "18:00 - SK Gaming vs. G2 (BO3)"]
```

Но у меня не получается разобрать его для использования в foreach, он либо не разбирается полностью, либо разбирается побуквенно.

Потыкал даже JavaScriptSerializer:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(streamname_result);
```

Но этот код не разбирает как надо.

Comment: Не совсем понятно — на входе _чего_?

Comment: @VladD Подправил

Comment: Всё равно не вполне ясно — в каком виде вы получаете это? Как одну большую строку? Как JSON?

Comment: @VladD в представленном виде она передается из javascript в переменную.

Comment: А если DeserializeObject? А вообще-то, вам нужен JSON.NET по идее.

Comment: @VladD не работает, это не JSON, а просто массив

Comment: Почему не JSON? Вполне себе JSON вроде.

Comment: «передается из javascript в переменную» — какого типа переменная?

Comment: @VladD JSValue (http://docs.awesomium.net/html/T_Awesomium_Core_JSValue.htm#)

строка кода JSValue streamname_result = webControl2.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult(streamname_request);

Comment: А, вот оно что! Так это ж ключевая информация, немедленно добавляйте в вопрос!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исходя из документации на awesomium ([[1]](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/M_Awesomium_Core_JSObject_GetPropertyNames.htm), [[2]](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/P_Awesomium_Core_JSObject_Property.htm)), вам нужно следующее:

```
JSObject streamname_result = webControl2.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult(streamname_request);
var strings = new List<string>();
foreach (var propertyName in streamname_result)
    strings.Add((string)streamname_result[propertyName]);
```

Или то же короче:

```
JSObject streamname_result = webControl2.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult(streamname_request);
var strings = streamname_result
                 .Select(propertyName => (string)streamname_result[propertyName])
                 .ToList();
```

Или, возможно, так:

```
JSObject streamname_result = webControl2.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult(streamname_request);
if (streamname_result.IsArray)
{
    var array = (JSValue[])streamname_result;
    var strings = array.Select(v => (string)v).ToList();
    ...
}
else
{
    // к нам пришёл не массив, надо что-то делать
}
```

Не знаю, который из вариантов правильный (у меня нет Awesomium'а).